Question about conjugate priors in the paper "Composing graphical models with neural networks for structured representations and fast inference"
I have been reading through the paper "Composing graphical models with neural networks for structured representations and fast inference", but am having trouble understanding the last line of the following screenshot.

Specifically, "because the observation model p(y | x, θ) is conjugate to the latent variable
model... the optimal factor q(x)... is itself a Gaussian linear dynamical system." Questions:

What do they mean by $q^*(x)$ being a linear dynamical system? Do they mean that $q^*(x)$ corresponds to the distribution of a linear dynamical system? If so, how might one mathematically show this?

I have been trying to show this unsuccessfully for a couple days, so any insight would be deeply appreciated :)

Your intuition sounds right. By Bayes theorem it's obvious that $p(\theta,x|y)$ is the posterior of the prior $p(x|\theta)$ and $p(y|x,\theta)$ is the likelihood, meanwhile the variational mean field family $q(\theta)q(x)$ is used to approximate the posterior $p(\theta,x|y)$, therefore the optimized factored $q^*(x)$ is approximating the true latent state posterior $p(x|y)$ which can be obtained by marginalizing out the parameter $\theta$ from the joint $p(\theta,x|y)$. In other words $q^*(x)$ itself is approximately the distribution of the said Gaussian linear dynamical system.
